# PostGraphile - ordering results by specific id

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

so I'm trying to do a query that fetches a certain id first.

i know the sql syntax is something along the lines of -

```
SELECT id, name, colour
FROM books
ORDER BY id=2 desc;
```

i am trying to figure out how to do the same thing in a postgraphile query with pagination

thank you very much!

Comment: too wide question, follow some tutorial

Comment: PostGraphile maintainer here; never had this request before! Simplest solution is a custom query: https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/custom-queries/